# Sort through all attributes in XML tree with PHP XMLReader

Tags: php, xml

I have some PHP code to turn an XML file into a CSV file.  During testing, I am not creating a CSV file, just echoing the results in a CSV format.

Whenever XMLReader reaches an empty element, it outputs all the attributes of the element.

1) Is there a way to output the attribute name with it's values i.e. (is there an $xml->AttributeName that goes with the $xml->value)?

2) Is there a way to sort for all attributes in the entire tree and not just those in the empty element?

```
<?php 

ini_set('memory_limit','50M');

$x = file_get_contents('H8_data.xml');

$xml = new XMLReader(); 
$xml->open('H8_data.xml', null, 1<<19); 

$num = 1;
while ($xml->read() && $num <= 2000) {
    if($xml->isEmptyElement) {
        if($xml->hasAttributes)  {
            while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) { 
                echo $xml->value, ', '; 
            }
        }
    echo '<br />';
    $num++;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Syntax error: echo $xml->value, ', '; should be echo $xml->value . ', ';  

??

Comment: actually both are acceptable. I would have to use the latter if I was creating a variable, but echo supports commas.

Comment: This is not a syntax error, echo accepts any number of arguments separated by commas.

Answer (score 5):

$xml->name returns the qualified name of the node. Because attributes are nodes with XMLReader::ATTRIBUTE type, $xml->name will return the name of current attribute in that case.
Below is version of code, which outputs both attribute names and values.

```
<?php 

ini_set('memory_limit','50M');

$x = file_get_contents('H8_data.xml');

$xml = new XMLReader(); 
$xml->open('H8_data.xml', null, 1<<19); 

$num = 1;
while ($xml->read() && $num <= 2000) {
    if($xml->isEmptyElement) {
        if($xml->hasAttributes)  {
            while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) { 
                echo $xml->name, ' = ', $xml->value, ', '; 
            }
        }
    echo '<br />';
    $num++;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$xml->name ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#xmlreader.props.name