# XMLReader - Get all namespaces in document

Tags: php, xml, php-7, xml-namespaces, xmlreader

Is there a way to get the namespaces in a XML document using XMLReader?
For now I am using `SimpleXMLElement::getDocNamespaces()` to do the job, but since I am working with rather big documents there is a drawback since (as far as I know) SimpleXML loads the whole document at once with respect to memory usage.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12652385/1213708 which shows how to read the attributes of a document using XMLReader, this just checks if the attribute has a prefix of `xmlns` and if it does, it adds it into a list of namespaces using prefix(which is the `localName` value)/URI (which is the attribute value)...

```
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open($fileName);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$namespaces = [];
while ($xml->read()) {
    if($xml->hasAttributes)  {
        while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) {
            if ( $xml->prefix == 'xmlns' ) {
                $namespaces [ $xml->localName ] = $xml->value;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($namespaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

To read XML with namespaces you do not need to know the prefix used in the document. You need to know and compare the namespace URI. So do not compare `XMLReader::$name` but
`XMLReader::$localName` and `XMLReader::$namespaceURI`.

Here are two valid reasons to read the namespace from the document.

1. Generic Conversion (like XML to JsonML)
2. Debugging

In this case iterate the elements descendants and read the attributes with the node name `xmlns` and the ones in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` namespace.

Be aware that only namespace URIs are unique. Prefixes are not unique or always necessary.

Demo:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:a" xmlns="urn:default" xmlns:b="urn:b">
  <f:bar xmlns:f="urn:c" xmlns="urn:a"/>
</f:foo>
XML;
$xmlUrl = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml);

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlUrl);

$namespaces = [];
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->hasAttributes) {
        while ($reader->moveToNextAttribute()) {
            if ($reader->name === 'xmlns') {
                $namespaces[$reader->value][] = '#default';
            } elseif ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/') {
                $namespaces[$reader->value][] = $reader->localName;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($namespaces);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["urn:a"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "#default"
  }
  ["urn:default"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#default"
  }
  ["urn:b"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  ["urn:c"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}
```